# How can I take the value of the first node with nested nodes?

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="media field-640">
  <div class="media-header">
    <div class="media-left hide-variant-icon">
      <h3>
        Third camera: </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body ">
      <ul class="actions">
      </ul>
      <span class="size-dimensions-container"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media field-644">
    <div class="media-left">
      <h3>
        Features:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <ul class="actions">
      </ul>
      Ultra-wide </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need an XPath that brings as result only the `<div class="media-body ">` when positioned over `<div class="media field-640">`

I'm trying with the following XPath:

```
$x('//div[@class="media field-640"]//div[contains(normalize-space(@class),"media-body")][1]')
```

It brings 2 results: the one I expected and the one corresponding to media field-644.
It seems to be ignoring the [1] index.

Comment: The node naming in you code is a little confusing (unless it's a typo). Both `<div class="media-body ">` are grand-child nodes of `<div class="media field-640">`. The first one is a child of `<div class="media-header">` and the other of `<div class="media field-644">`. Which one are you after?

Comment: I am after the one that is child of  <div class="media-header">, which is also the first one, that's why I'm using the [1] index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could solve the problem by changing my xpath from:

`$x('//div[@class="media field-640"]//div[contains(normalize-space(@class),"media-body")][1]')`
to

`$x('//div[@class="media field-640"]/descendant::div[contains(normalize-space(@class),"media-body")][1]')`

I think the double slash brings firstly all div[contains(normalize-space(@class),"media-body")] and then applies the index filter to each one, so it brings the [1] for every div that fitted the filter.

Comment: Since you are the OP, you are entitled to decide on the answer :), but I would argue that your solution isn't "true" to the structure of the html. In your place, I would use `//div[@class="media field-640"]/div[@class="media-header"]/div[contains(normalize-space(@class),"media-body")]`. This way, no positional arguments are required (which may be a problem if the order of child nodes is changed, for example.)

Comment: I understand and appreciate your point but it isn't a valid solution in my case, because in the real life, i'm not only looking for media field-640, but for every media-field. The xpath I finally chose is `'//div[contains(@class,"specs-table")]//div[contains(@class,"media field")]/descendant::div[contains(normalize-space(@class),"media-body")][1]//text()'`. As you can see in the HTML, the media field-644 hasn't any ancestor @class="media header" and would be lost.